# Laravel Eager Loading with intermediate association table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm trying to optimize my API applying eager loading on some models that have relationships.

For example, I have a lot of models with `$appends` property and many `getXXXAttribute()` methods to retrieve related data. But this isn't the best way (I think) to achieve that. I'm afraid to create a loop somewhere (for example, when getting an User that has Addresses, and each Addresss retrieves it's User, but the User retrieves it's Addresses and each Address retrieve his User and each User[...]), so I'm adding eager loading to improve that and prevent errors.

But, I'm facing a question that I can't find a solution. I have an **addresses** table that has no direct relationship with any other model. Each model (for example, *Client* and *User*) has a table (**client_addresses** and **user_addresses**) which makes the relationship, containing only the *address_id* and the *<entity>_id* columns.

Explaining:

```
addresses
    - id
    - address
    - complement
    - number
    - postal_code
    - city
    - state

user_addresses
    - id
    - user_id
    - address_id

client_addresses
    - id
    - client_id
    - address_id
```

To retrieve User's addresses, I'm doing this query in my model:

```php
protected $appends = ["addresses"];

public function getAddressesAttribute()
{
    return Address::select("addresses.*")
                    ->join("user_addresses", "user_addresses.address_id", "=", "addresses.id")
                    ->join("users", "user_addresses.boat_id", "=", "users.id")
                    ->where("users.id", $this->id)
                    ->get();
}
```

How can I convert this complex query that has two joins to eager loading? Checking the Laravel Eloquent docs, I've checked there are some "somethingThrough" functions, but I don't properly understood how to use them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can use belongsToMany https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-table-structure

In User Model:

```
public function addresses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Address::class, 'user_addresses');
}
```

And then, you can apply eager loading, such as:

```
User::with('addresses')->first()
```